# AttributeError: 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'getElementsByTagName'

Tags: python, xml, dom

I am trying to extract text contents from a xml file. The xml file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<brca:tcga_bcr xsi:schemaLocation="http://tcga.nci/bcr/xml/clinical/brca/2.7 http://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/docs/xsd/BCR/tcga.nci/bcr/xml/clinical/brca/2.7/TCGA_BCR.BRCA_Clinical.xsd" schemaVersion="2.7" xmlns:brca="http://tcga.nci/bcr/xml/clinical/brca/2.7" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:admin="http://tcga.nci/bcr/xml/administration/2.7" xmlns:clin_shared="http://tcga.nci/bcr/xml/clinical/shared/2.7" xmlns:shared="http://tcga.nci/bcr/xml/shared/2.7" xmlns:brca_shared="http://tcga.nci/bcr/xml/clinical/brca/shared/2.7" xmlns:shared_stage="http://tcga.nci/bcr/xml/clinical/shared/stage/2.7" xmlns:brca_nte="http://tcga.nci/bcr/xml/clinical/brca/shared/new_tumor_event/2.7/1.0" xmlns:nte="http://tcga.nci/bcr/xml/clinical/shared/new_tumor_event/2.7" xmlns:rx="http://tcga.nci/bcr/xml/clinical/pharmaceutical/2.7" xmlns:rad="http://tcga.nci/bcr/xml/clinical/radiation/2.7">
    <admin:admin>
        <admin:bcr xsd_ver="1.17">Nationwide Children's Hospital</admin:bcr>
        <admin:file_uuid xsd_ver="2.6">6CEF6ECD-264E-4DF6-8419-9E4C564DA7B2</admin:file_uuid>
        <admin:batch_number xsd_ver="1.17">85.84.0</admin:batch_number>
        <admin:project_code xsd_ver="">TCGA</admin:project_code>
        <admin:disease_code xsd_ver="2.6">BRCA</admin:disease_code>
        <admin:day_of_dcc_upload xsd_ver="1.17">21</admin:day_of_dcc_upload>
        <admin:month_of_dcc_upload xsd_ver="1.17">1</admin:month_of_dcc_upload>
        <admin:year_of_dcc_upload xsd_ver="1.17">2016</admin:year_of_dcc_upload>
        <admin:patient_withdrawal>
            <admin:withdrawn>false</admin:withdrawn>
        </admin:patient_withdrawal>
    </admin:admin>
```

I got the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'getElementsByTagName'

I am using python 2.7. Here is a part of my code. I could not figure out what's wrong. Any suggestions?

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('A0SD.xml')
bcr = xmldoc.getElementsByTagNameNS('*','tcga_bcr')
patient_info = bcr.getElementsByTagName('admin')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagNameNS` returns a list of all of the nodes with the specified tag. So `bcr` is a `NodeList`. You can't ask for `getElemnetsByTagName` of a `NodeList`, only of a `Node`. You will need to iterate over `bcr` to get the `admin` tags in each node. Or if you expect there to be exactly one `tcga_bcr` tag, then you can just take the first element of the list:

```
bcr = xmldoc.getElementsByTagNameNS('*','tcga_bcr')[0]
```